# Completion block for multiple SKAction on different nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

For example I have an array with nodes that subclass SKSpriteNode. How can I run same action on all nodes from array, and have a single completion block for all actions at once?
I work on a tile game and want to make a chain reaction, when some tiles are destroyed, at the end of their destroy to make another call of same function to check for more chains (recursion).
What I have now is also working fine, but there are no delays between chains. How I can achieve this? Check below my current code.
Thanks in advance!

```
func checkTilesAndDestroy(inout tilesToCheck: [Tile]) {

    if tilesToCheck.count == 0 { return }

    let firstTileToCheck = tilesToCheck.removeAtIndex(0)

    let tilesToDestroy: [Tile] = self.getNeighbours(firstTileToCheck)

    if tilesToDestroy.count >= 3 {

        for tile in tilesToDestroy {

            /* some code here */

            if /* some code here */ {
                /* some code here */

                if /* some code here */ {
                    /* some code here */
                    tilesToCheck.append(anotherTile)
                } else {
                    /* some code here */
                }

                /* some code here */
            }

            tile.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0, duration: 0.1)) {
                tile.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }

    checkTilesAndDestroy(&tilesToCheck)
}
```

I would like to be something like this.

```
func checkTilesAndDestroy(inout tilesToCheck: [Tile]) {

    if tilesToCheck.count == 0 { return }

    let firstTileToCheck = tilesToCheck.removeAtIndex(0)

    let tilesToDestroy: [Tile] = self.getNeighbours(firstTileToCheck)

    if tilesToDestroy.count >= 3 {
        for tile in tilesToDestroy {
            /* some code here */
        }
    }

    self.runAction(SKAction.runBlock({
        for tile in tilesToDestroy {
            tile.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0, duration: 0.1)) {
                tile.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    })) { [unowned self] in

        /* here al tiles actions are completed */
        self.checkTilesAndDestroy(&tilesToCheck)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a workaround that works perfect.

```
func checkTilesAndDestroy(inout tilesToCheck: [Tile]) {

    if tilesToCheck.count == 0 { return }

    let firstTileToCheck = tilesToCheck.removeAtIndex(0)

    let tilesToDestroy: [Tile] = self.getNeighbours(firstTileToCheck)

    if tilesToDestroy.count >= 3 {

        for tile in tilesToDestroy {

            /* some code here */

            tile.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0, duration: 0.1)) {
                tile.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }

    if tilesToCheck.count != 0 {
        self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1)) { [unowned self] in
            self.checkTilesAndDestroy(&tilesToCheck)
        }
    }
}
```